# How to make Kibana 4 visualizer on dashboard not resizable?

Tags: kibana-4

Recently started using Kibana 4.
I am not getting how to make Kibana 4 visualizer on dashboard not resizable?

and in visualizer there is option to see table,request,response how to hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I figured out was like following "kibana" is id of my iframe which is loading kibana dashboard. on its onload event I am calling a function and kept following code in that.

```
$("#kibana").contents().find('img').hide();
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#kibana").contents().find('visualize-spy').remove();            
        }, 2500);
```

this code just hide it.

You can apply this solution to even make visible timepicker or anything from topmenu bar of kibana4.